Can a mixed effects regression model overdispersion?
Take the common Poisson GLM:
$$ Y_i \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda_i) $$
$$ \log(\lambda_i) = X_i\beta $$
$$ L(\beta | Y) = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{e^{-\lambda_i} \lambda_i^{y_i}}{y_i!} $$
$$ = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{e^{-\exp(X_i\beta)} \exp(X_i\beta)^{y_i}}{y_i!} $$
$$ E(Y_i) = \lambda_i = \exp(X_i\beta) $$
$$ \text{Var}(Y_i) = \lambda_i = \exp(X_i\beta) $$
If I have count data and I believe that a Poisson Regression is a good choice - but then I notice that the mean and the variance of the data are not equal, this violates the assumption of the Poisson Distribution. In such cases, we can add an overdispersion parameter to take this into consideration. However, doing this, we no longer have an exact likelihood, but a Quadi-Likelihood:
$$
E(Y) = \mu
$$
$$
\text{Var}(Y) = \phi\mu
$$
$$
Q(\mu; y) = \int_{y}^{\mu} \frac{y - t}{\phi t} dt
$$
$$
l(\mu; y) = \frac{y \log(\mu) - \mu}{\phi}
$$
$$
L(\mu; y) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{y_i \log(\mu_i) - \mu_i}{\phi}
$$
I had the following question: Suppose we define a  mixed effects regression model based on the Poisson Distribution:
$$ Y_i | u_i \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda_i) $$
$$ \log(\lambda_i) = X_i\beta + u_i $$
$$ u_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2_u) $$
$$ L(\beta, \sigma^2_u | Y) = \prod_{i=1}^n \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\exp(X_i\beta + u_i)} \exp(X_i\beta + u_i)^{y_i}}{y_i!} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2_u}} \exp(-\frac{u_i^2}{2\sigma^2_u}) du_i $$
If we write the mean and variance of the poisson regression with random effects:
$$ E(Y_i) = E(E(Y_i|u_i)) = E(\exp(X_i\beta + u_i)) $$
$$ = \exp(X_i\beta) E(\exp(u_i)) = \exp(X_i\beta + \frac{\sigma^2_u}{2}) $$
$$ \begin{align*}
\text{Var}(Y_i) &= E(\text{Var}(Y_i|u_i)) + \text{Var}(E(Y_i|u_i)) \\
&= E(\lambda_i) + \text{Var}(\lambda_i) \\
&= \exp(X_i\beta + \frac{\sigma^2_u}{2}) + [\exp(2X_i\beta + \sigma^2_u)](\exp(\sigma^2_u) - 1)
\end{align*} $$
I can now see that the mean and variance of this mixed effects Poisson regression now has an extra term which looks like it implicitly accounts for overdispersion. Thus, it seems like a Poisson Regression with overdispersion can actually be written as well using a full likelihood instead of solely a quasi-likelihood - is this the correct interpretation?

What you did is compounding a Poisson distribution with a rate parameter distributed according to a log normal distribution. That leads indeed to overdispersion (a quotient of conditional variance and mean that is larger than what occurs with a plain Poisson).
An example of a well known distribution that also arises as an overdispersed Poisson distribution is the negative binomial distribution. That is a commonly used model for overdispersed count distributions.

Thus, it seems like a Poisson Regression with overdispersion can actually be written as well using a full likelihood instead of solely a quasi-likelihood - is this the correct interpretation?

The likelihood functions of these different distributions, your mixed effects model, the negative binomial distribution, the quasi Poisson likelihood, they are not the same and will lead to different fits/estimates of E[Y|X].
The interpretation of all these models as 'Poisson Regression with overdispersion' is a bit semantical and also dependent on definitions. You can regard negative binomial distribution as a Poisson model with overdispersion, but it is not the overdispersed model (the model created by adding a dispersion parameter).

Another example is the discrete compound Poisson distribution, defined as a sum of iid discrete variables $\sum_{i=0}^N X_i$ where $N$ is Poisson distributed. An example where $X_i$ is binomial distributed is in How much dispersion is too much for quasipoisson regression?

Example, a pirate ship full of chests filled with coins exploded in front of the coast and the chests are spreading along the coast following a Poisson distribution, but we don't count the chests (say that they have rotten away) and instead we count the coins that came from the chest (say 500 coins in each chest with a 90% probability of finding a coin).


thank you ...  so i guess the correct interpretation is : while a poisson GLM with random effects is not meant to model overdispersion - it indirectly does this. Correct?

@user430997 it does model a distribution where the variance is larger than the expectation and as such it models overdispersion in a seemingly Poisson distributed case (one of the many ways how it can arrise). It does not mean that it is equivalent to the addition of a dispersion parameter to the likelihood function. ––– Overdispersion, a discrepancy from a simple/plain/ordinary Poisson model can arrise in many different ways. So yes, "overdispersion can actually be written as well using a full likelihood", but it is not the same as the quasi likelihood overdispersion.
